# Active page on a website?

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm wanting to basically make it so that on my website when the user clicks on a navigation bar button it changes the image. Of which on the image I have set the text on the button to display in a different colour.

So far I've developed the following css:

```
#HomeOver
{
    width: 188px;
    height: 54px;
    background: url("Images/Navbar_01.gif");
}

#HomeOver:active 
{
    background: url("Images/NavbarOver_01.gif");
}


#HomeOver:hover
{ 
    background: url("Images/NavbarOver_01.gif");
}
```

The HTML then links the ID to the CSS to display the correct image.. But my problem is, on the "active", it doesn't seem to work, Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the coding? The hover works fine

Comment: `:active` and `:hover` are both using the same image. Is that intended?

Comment: use .active class it will work

Comment: I just basically want it so once a button is clicked on the navbar it changes the image until a different button is pressed, where it's then reset, do you know the code for it ?

Comment: @MarcusEkwall yeah it's intended

Comment: @user2985995 That would have to be done with JavaScript or radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#HomeOver.active {
    background: url("Images/NavbarOver_01.gif");
}
```

Then just add the "active" class to the navigation button either through JavaScript or directly in the html for the corresponding page.

Comment: Thanks, was the most simple way to solve it, works now, thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 4):

`:active` pseudo only works when an element is *kept clicked*, as soon as you leave the click, the effect goes, you can achieve the *active* tabs, by either using client side scripting such as JavaScript/jQuery and assign a `class` to the intended element, or assign it by using server side scripting such as PHP.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGzN8/) *(How actually `:active` pseudo works)*

---

Achieving this with jQuery...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8s9Pd/)

```
var active_menu = $('nav a').click(function(){ //onclick of a nested inside nav 
    active_menu.removeClass('active'); //Remove all the classes first
    $(this).addClass('active'); //Assign the class to the a which is clicked
});
```

Comment: Ah right, I didn't realise that, do you have any idea how to make it so once it's clicked it sets to that colour until something else is clicked ?

Comment: @user2985995 sharing a jquery demo

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Alien stated the pseude class `:active` does only work as long as you keep the mousebutton clicked. To achieve a permanent active state you will have to use jquery to change the class on click.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sDCL2/)

js

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

css

```
div:active,
div.active {
    color: #f00;
}
```

or you have to give the acitve element the .active class when generating it serverside with php or so:

```
print '<div' . (active ? ' class="active"' : '') . '></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` on click using jquery

Comment: This is a very poor answer, no code examples or any kind of explanation

Comment: please delete or edit your answer so I can remove the downvote and regain my rep point

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use JavaScript you can instead use `input:radio` instead.

**HTML**

```
<div id="links">
    <label><input type="radio" name="links" /><div class="image"></div></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="links" /><div class="image"></div></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="links" /><div class="image"></div></label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#links input {
    display: none;
}

#links .image {
    background: url("Images/Navbar_01.gif");
}

#links label:hover .image,
#links input:checked ~ .image {
    background: url("Images/NavbarOver_01.gif");
}
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/Sn2we/).